# Pandoc options to convert LaTeX flavored Markdown to HTML

Tags: conversion, html, latex, markdown, pandoc

The aim is to convert a Markdown file (`file.md`) to a html file (`file.html`).

The Markdown file contains formulas specified in LaTeX specified between two dollar (`$`) signs.

**Example:**

```
The resulting formula is
$p\left(n,k,i\right)=\dfrac{{n-i-1 \choose k-1}}{{n \choose k}}$
```

But the resulting `.html` file only contains `$p(n,k,i)=$` with nothing in the raw html source code to render the rest of the formula and with the dollars shown explicitly.

How can one convert LaTeX-flavored markdown to the html equivalent?

The conversion is done with `pandoc` using the following flags:

```
pandoc --from markdown-tex_math_dollars -t html file.md
```

Pandoc version:

```
pandoc 1.12.2.1
Compiled with texmath 0.6.5.2, highlighting-kate 0.5.5.1.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently `markdown-tex_math_dollars` means disabling the `tex_math_dollars` feature instead of enabling it. (The minus). If one simply writes `markdown`, the math is interpreted. One can use one of the options shown [here](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/example19/Extension-tex_005fmath_005fdollars.html) to select how the math should be rendered.